# What can I build/use for a door in an old barn?

Tags: doors, barn

I have a very small barn/chicken coop on my land that we basically use as a shed.  It currently has a standard door on it.  However I just got a new riding lawnmower and would like to store it in said barn.  It needs a ramp (there is a lip) and it won't fit through the door.

I am looking for ideas on what kind of door I could use/make.  The door is situated about 8 inches from one of the corners of the barn and there are no other windows on the door side.  If I were to slap on a 36" hinged door it would open to the inside and be hitting a window on the perpendicular wall.

Cheap would be great, easy to use is a plus, cool looking, and most of all sturdy.  I may lock the door (in any way) but security isn't a huge issue as someone who was looking to steal things would have other entries.

Comment: Why would a 36" hinged door necessarily open to the inside? Couldn't you put on a normal door that swings out?

Comment: @ShimonRura - I could but then that may increase the chances of the door getting torn up or damaged while out of the barn.  Actually my biggest concern would probably be my kids using it as a swing.

Answer (score 5):

One simple and classic option would be a sliding barn door:

[image: Barn door example]

You can make the door whatever size you want. You attach a rail to the outside of your shed, some rollers to the top of the door, a handle, and perhaps some retaining or locking hardware. You can make the door in a traditional rails/stiles approach or just cut a piece of plywood to size and paint it.

Here's one idea for a cool look with moderate effort. I haven't done this but am considering it for some new shed doors.

1. Get a piece of plywood and cut it to size.
2. Attach 1x6 wood along its outer edge so it looks like it has stiles.
3. Cut some lights. You can do simple rectangular ones or get fancy with a jigsaw and cut in some fun designs, your initials, whatever. Because you're working with a piece of plywood you have a lot of options.
4. Prime & paint with good exterior paint.
5. Attach some acrylic/plexiglass behind your lights (glue, caulk, and/or window glazing compound depending on your design, plus a few screws around the edges).

Comment: I like this.  I guess the main issue I have is the tracking system.  Not sure I have seen a cheap alternative for something like this - but haven't really looked.

Comment: A quick look online suggests that you can get an exterior-grade rail, rail brackets, two rollers, and a bumper for about $80-90. Plus say $20 for lumber. Definitely not the cheapest door option, but possibly the coolest. :)

Comment: I did this: worked great on my shed: http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-sliding-barn-doors-using-skateboard-wheels/